# Como definir Rendered parametro via bean JSF 2

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

estou enfrentando um pequeno desafio onde preciso criar um dashboard dinamicamente a partir de um drop down.

Ele esta funcional porém existe um botão em cada Panel que a renderização dele depende da existencia outro panel.

Lógica:

Se PanelCidade existir PanelEstado não pode renderizar o botão.

No meu Bean eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
CommandButton excluirBtn = new CommandButton();
excluirBtn.setIcon("fa fa-trash");
excluirBtn.setTitle("Remover");
excluirBtn.setActionExpression(methodExpression);
excluirBtn.processUpdates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
excluirBtn.setUpdate("dashboard");
excluirBtn.setRendered(!hasComponentOnDashbaord("panel_3")); //<-Linha que impede renderização do componente se o painel existir.
```

Ele funciona corretamente na hora de criar Porém ele não checa depois que ele foi renderizado se o Panel foi excluido.

Como fazer isso de forma dinamica pelo Bean ?

Comment: Pensou e em criar um atributo boleano para informar se o panelCidade deve ou não ser exibido e negá-lo para renderizar o botão ?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo,

Tenta usar um f:ajax com o atributo event=para disparar o evento e um listener ou action para executar chamar o método do ManagedBean e o atributo render para atualizar o outro painel.
Não seria a melhor solução e menos trabalhosa? Eu nunca criei usei de outra forma.
Espero que ajude.